# How to change innerHTML of a table cell

Tags: javascript

I have an editRow function which should enable text-box instead of the text that was before in there cell innerHTML. I need to update the cell innerHTML so that instead of text, it should be a textbox with the text inside it. I tried this but did not do the job:

```
function edit(index)
{   
    var currentRow=document.getElementById("row-"+index);
    var textBox=document.createElement('input');
    textBox.type= "text";
    textBox.id= "text-box"+(index);
    textBox.innerHTML= currentRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
    currentRow.cells[0].innerHTML = textBox ; 
}
```

I need something like `appenChild` but replaces the old content rather thna appending to it.

Comment: `textBox` is an input, it has a value, but can't contain other elements?

Comment: I want its value to be the current text in that cell. I might have user value attribute instead of innerHTML??

Comment: Then you'd use the `value` property, not the `innerHTML` property. Still, `textBox` is an element, and an object, it can't be set as `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `value` for `input` instead of `innerHTML`, and clear `td` before appending an `input`:

```js
function edit(index) {   
    var currentRow=document.getElementById("row-"+index);
    var textBox=document.createElement('input');
    textBox.type= "text";
    textBox.id= "text-box"+(index);
    textBox.value= currentRow.cells[0].innerHTML; // set input value
    currentRow.cells[0].innerHTML = null; // delete previous innerHTML
    currentRow.cells[0].appendChild(textBox) // add child
}

edit(1)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row-1"><td>Hello</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```